# How do I force clean urls with htaccess when mod rewrite enabled?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, clean-urls

I'm trying that htaccess redirects all pages from `.php` to `.html` when mod rewrite is enabled. But I also want that in behind the scene, the server "serves" the `.php` files when recieving a `.html` request.

For example, I go to my website `example.com/folder/file.html`, so the server should render `/folder/file.php` and send it. But if I write in my browser `example.com/folder/file.php`, I want that the server redirects me to `example.com/folder/file.html`, and then, run the php code.

I want this so when mod_rewrite is enabled, my site will have the .html extensions, but when it is disabled, it will use the .php extensions.

What i tried to do is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html [R=307]
```

but it throws an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired behavior, you need to ensure that your rules don't create an infinite loop. Your current rules are causing a loop because both rules can be applied to the same request, resulting in a continuous redirection between .php and .html.

Here's an updated version of your .htaccess file to avoid the infinite loop:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Prevent internal redirect for existing files and directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    
    # Rewrite .html to .php internally
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
    
    # Redirect external requests from .php to .html
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.html [R=307,L]
```

Explanation:

1. The first `RewriteCond` checks if the requested file or directory does not exist as a physical file or directory on the server.
2. The second `RewriteCond` checks if the requested file does not exist as a physical file on the server.
3. The first `RewriteRule` internally rewrites requests from .html to .php without redirecting the browser. The `[L]` flag indicates that this is the last rule to be processed if the conditions are met.
4. The second set of conditions (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`) checks if the request contains .php. If so, it redirects the browser to the corresponding .html file. The `[R=307,L]` flag performs a temporary (307) redirect and stops processing further rules.

With these rules, you should be able to achieve the desired behavior without causing an infinite loop.